# Unit testing with final classes of AWS SDK

Tags: java, unit-testing, amazon-web-services, mockito, aws-lambda

I have written following code to publish some metrics around AWS Step function (its java lambda for aws)

```
@Override
public void handleRequest(InputStream input, OutputStream output, Context context) throws IOException {
    int inProgressStateMachines = 0;

    LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();

    long alarmThreshold = getAlarmThreshold(input, context.getLogger());

    AWSStepFunctions awsStepFunctions = AWSStepFunctionsClientBuilder.standard().build();

    ListStateMachinesRequest listStateMachinesRequest = new ListStateMachinesRequest();
    ListStateMachinesResult listStateMachinesResult = awsStepFunctions.listStateMachines(listStateMachinesRequest);

    for (StateMachineListItem stateMachineListItem : listStateMachinesResult.getStateMachines()) {

        ListExecutionsRequest listExecutionRequest = new ListExecutionsRequest()
                .withStateMachineArn(stateMachineListItem.getStateMachineArn())
                .withStatusFilter(ExecutionStatus.RUNNING);

        ListExecutionsResult listExecutionsResult = awsStepFunctions.listExecutions(listExecutionRequest);

        for (ExecutionListItem executionListItem : listExecutionsResult.getExecutions()) {

            LocalDateTime stateMachineStartTime = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(
                    executionListItem.getStartDate().toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault());

            long elapsedTime = ChronoUnit.SECONDS.between(stateMachineStartTime, now);

            if (elapsedTime > alarmThreshold){
                inProgressStateMachines++;
            }
        }

        publishMetrics(inProgressStateMachines);
    }
}
```

Now I am trying to unit-test this method and having some issues.

First of all, I get error that `Mockito can not mock final class` when i tried to mock `AWSStepFunctionsClientBuilder`.

Secondly, I have private methods which are being called with specific params.

The question is

1. How can i unit test this code? I read it somewhere that if a code isn't unit-testable then its a bad design. How can i improve this code so that its easily testable? I would prefer to keep those helper methods as `private` methods.
2. How can i mock `final` objects from `AWS SDK` to test this code? I can not use any other framework but `Mockito`.

Comment: encapsulate 3rd party dependencies behind abstraction you control to be able to mock/stub/fake them and improve testability of your code.

Comment: could you share some example?

Comment: Too broad given the current example provided. suggest reading up on SOLID principle. it will help your design IMO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually don't want to mock `AWSStepFunctionsClientBuilder` because you are actually calling `AWSStepFunctions`, which you'll have to mock anyway even after mocking the builder.

So make `AWSStepFunctions` an instance variable:

```
// add appropriate getter/setter as well
private AWSStepFunctions awsStepFunctions;
```

Where you currently call the builder to initialize `awsStepFunctions`, change to:

```
if (awsStepFunctions == null)
    awsStepFunctions = AWSStepFunctionsClientBuilder.standard().build();
```

Now, during unit test, you can set `awsStepFunctions` to a mocked instance, bypassing the conditional initialization above.

[Edit] Some more thoughts based on @kdgregory's comment below:

The answer above is meant to provide a solution given the existing code structure, without requiring any major refactoring. In general though, ideally you would want to move the bulk of the code into another plain, more testable Java class, where you can properly inject dependencies, manage life cycles, etc.

Comment: Generally a good answer (so +1), but I think the lazy instantiation of the client is a bad idea. Instead, it should be injected into the object (either via constructor or setter method). This will also encourage sharing a client object, which is a general best practice for AWS services.

Comment: @kdgregory Agreed. See my updated answer for more thoughts on this.